# How i can insert contact form 7 short-code in twig file

Tags: wordpress, twig

I want to show contact form which i am using into 
but shorcode not showing form on frontend
How can I show contact form 7 with .twig file?

```
 <div class="our_form">
    {{ wp.do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="766" title="Contact form 1"]') }}
    </div>

    <form action="{{ post.link }}" class="contact-form" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
        <div class="contact-form__row">
            {% spaceless %}
                {{ form_row(form.name, {}) }}

                {{ form_row(form.email, {}) }}

                {{ form_row(form.subject, {}) }}
            {% endspaceless %}
        </div>

        {{ form_row(form.message, {}) }}

        {{ form_widget(form) }}

        <button class="btn btn--primary caps">Send</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

how about running this like that:

```
{% filter shortcodes %}
[contact-form-7 id="766" title="Contact form 1"]
{% endfilter %}
```

Reference: https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/wp-integration/#shortcodes